# I want to link a google chrome extension popup button action with the content of the page

Tags: google-chrome, manifest

I'm just having a hard day trying to figure out this but still couldn't get anywhere, I have a google chrome extension built with manifest v3 which is the latest version supported by google, Inside this extension i have a popup html file that opens up when you click on the extension icon
[image]

- What i want is, when i click the "change background" button the background of the active tab/page changes to red
- What i tried is doing it without the popup thing and it worked! when you click on the icon it actually changes the background color of the active page here is the code for the files used:

## manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Action script injection demo",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Click to show an alert",
    "default_popup": "./popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

## popup.html

```
<html>
    <header>
    </header>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Change background" id="btnChangeBackground" />
    </body>
</html>
```

## background.js

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    files: ['content.js']
  });
});
```

## content.js

```
document.querySelector("body").style = "background-color:red;";
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried your code, there are a couple problems and therefore a number of ways to solve this. The simplest soultion is to remove ```"default_popup"``` from your action key. The chrome.action.onClicked won't work if you have a default popup set. After I removed that, I was able to click the extension icon to change the color of a button on a page.